# What do the colors in `yarn list` mean?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

When I run [`yarn list`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/list/), modules are shown in either white or a faded grey color:

```
$ yarn list --pattern '@mycompany/foo-api'
yarn list v1.19.0
├─ WHITE @mycompany/some-module@1.0.0
│  └─ WHITE @mycompany/foo-api@1.0.17
└─ GREY @mycompany/foo-api@1.0.15
Done in 0.72s.
```

[There is no documentation on the colors](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/list/). What do the colors in `yarn list` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been raised as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7118). In my perspective, it's a contrast between bold and non-bold rather than a color issue. In a nutshell,

- **'bold**' (white) refers to non-hoisted dependents.
- The term 'dim'(grey) refers to hoisted child dependencies.

[Need documentation of what does the color mean in yarn list output](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7118)